# Issue with render or redirect_to in rails during ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to redirect using ajax request(setting remote: :true for form) in rails. This is the issue i have.

In the controller, I have:

```
def create
  user = User.new
  user.attributes = params[:user]

   if user.save
    if request.xhr?
      flash[:notice] = "User successfully created"
      render js: %('#{user_url(user.id)}')
    end
  else
    if request.xhr?
      render partial: "form"
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

in model,

```
class user
  validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than: 0}
end
```

in the view, the javascript is:

```
$("#new_user").bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data){
if(data.length < 300){
    window.location.replace(data.replace(/['\s]/gi, '')); # on success rendering the url. 
  }
  else {
    $("#errors").html($(data)); # if there are any errors, i have a div tag around form, which will replace the form html
  }
});
```

When i click on submit(it is an ajax request) leaving total amount as 0.0 for the user(which is required), i get validation error which is the expected behavior (and the validation errors are displayed, this is the else part in the javascript). 
Now i enter the amount as 1.0 and click on submit (this is an ajax request too). It is not going to the if part in the javascript.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the length of the data, you should use `ajax:error` and `ajax:success` as two different callbacks. Error callback displaying errors, success redirecting.

Callbacks: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Comment: Its firing `ajax:success` for both the cases. No idea why.